# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy after calling an express endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

In my frontend I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id="textInput">
    <button id="convertButton" onclick="convertTTS()">Convert</button>

    <script>
        function convertTTS() {
            // Creating Our XMLHttpRequest object 
            var url = 'localhost:5500/convertTextToMp3/';
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Making our connection  
            xhttp.open("GET", url, true);

            // function execute after request ist successful
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log("It works!");
                }
            };

            // Sending our request
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my backend, running by nodejs:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function myFunction() {
    console.log("My function!");
}

app.get('/convertTextToMp3', (req, res) => {
    myFunction();
    res.send('Function called successfully!');
});

app.listen(5500, () => console.log('Server started on port 5500'));
```

I try to call the function "myFunction" (which is running on the server) after pressing a button "#convertButton" (client side).

Because I can't call a function directly from frontend, I added a endpoint using express.

I expect to see a console log "Function called successfully".
But instead I get:
[image]

Comment: The origin identity is based on what the host name part of the URL looks like. Therefore "localhost" is not the same as "127.0.0.1" as far as the browser is concerned.

Comment: if I set the url to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it resolves to this: 

http://127.0.0.1:5500/127.0.0.1:5500/convertTextToMp3/

Comment: Start the URL with "http://" to ensure that it's treated as an absolute URL.

Comment: Now I get: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/convertTextToMp3/ 404 (Not Found)

Also: If I type in the browser directly 127.0.0.1:5500/convertTextToMp3 I get "Cannot GET /convertTextToMp3", but if I type "localhost:5500/converTextToMp3" I get "Function called successfully"

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install cors npm and configure it on your backend. Check [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) on how to set it up.

Comment: I tried the simple usage as described in the docs: I added var cors = require('cors') aswell as app.use(cors()) but it still shows the same issue